# Verilog: how to elegantly write the equivalent of a table of struct

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have the following C code:

```
typedef struct label {
    uint16_t first;
    uint8_t second;
} label;
label labelsr[2][64];

labelsr[1][3].second = 0;
```

I want to translate this into Verilog, the most elegantly possible way. So far, I came with the following. Is there anything better?

```
//(16 + 8) * 64 * 2 = 3072
`define LABELSR_STRUCT_SIZE 3072:0
`define ADVL 24
`define ADVLS 1536
`define FIRSTSTART 0
`define FIRSTEND 15
`define SECONDSTART 16
`define SECONDEND 23
`define FIRST(i, j) `FIRSTEND + i * `ADVLS + j * `ADVL : `FIRSTSTART + i * `ADVLS + j * `ADVL
`define SECOND(i, j) `SECONDEND + i * `ADVLS + j * `ADVL : `SECONDSTART + i * `ADVLS + j * `ADVL
reg [`LABELSR_STRUCT_SIZE] labelsr;

labelsr[`SECOND(1, 3)] <= 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... it'll never be elegant, but you can clean it up a bit. I assume you want classic Verilog, rather than SystemVerilog.

You need to use an 'indexed part select'. If you want 8 descending bits from `myvec`, and the MSB is `msb`, then write `myvec[msb -: 8]`. So `myvec[20 -: 8]` is `myvec[20:13]`. This will get rid of maybe half of your code.

And don't underestimate your synthesiser - it will probably do this sort of thing in the most optimal way even if you don't bother to break everything down for it.

Note also that `3072:0` should be `3071:0`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to get rid of the struct notation in verilog. it might simplify all significantly

```
`define INDEX(i, j) (i * 64 + j)
module A;
  parameter SSIZE = 2 * 64; 
  reg [15:0] first[SSIZE];
  reg [7:0] second[SSIZE];

  always @*
      second[`INDEX(1,3)] = 0; 
endmodule
```

and if you have access to a system verilog compiler, use struct:

```
typedef struct packed { 
  logic [15:0] first;
  logic [7:0] second;
} label_t;

module A;
 label_t label[2][64]; 
 always @*
   label[1][3].second = 0;
endmodule
```

well, icarus 0.10 does **not** compile the last example.

Comment: This post would also deserve to be the answer but I couldn't select both EML and yours at the same time! Thanks anyway for your efforts. I have upgraded it to give you something.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is using SystemVerilog which has the exact same C syntax. All modern tools support this.

Comment: Icarus, for one, won't support this. Not exactly sign-off, but more than adequate for running vast numbers of unit tests for free.